# VueJS | How can i get url parameters in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm making my own websites. and i'm newbie vue.js
I'm trying to get parameters to url.
I've been trying to any method. but not works.
Here is a url. -> example.com:8080/login
in this page, there's a button to register.
All i want is when i give url parameter(example.com:8080/login?id=hello&pw=1234), in login.vue, insert value -> user_id = hello, user_pw = 1234 and going back to exapmle.com:/8080
i'm trying to using vue.router. but it not works.
the error is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!
```

and this is /router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Main from '../views/Main.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Intro from '../views/Intro.vue'
import Info from '../views/Info.vue'
import Setting from '../views/Setting.vue'
import store from '../store'
import user_id from '../views/Login.vue'
import user_pw from '../views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/main',
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: '/signup',
        name: '/signup',
        component: SignUp
    },
    {
        path: '/main',
        component: Main,
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            if (store.state.accessToken) {
                next();
            } else {
                next('/login');
            }
        },
        children: [{
                path: '',
                name: 'intro',
                component: Intro,
            },
            {
                path: '/info',
                name: 'info',
                component: Info,
            },
            {
                path: '/setting',
                name: 'setting',
                component: Setting,
            },
        ]
    },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: Login
});

var myApp = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function() {
        let parameters;
        parameters = this.$route.query
        console.log(parameters)

        user_id = this.$route.query.id
        user_pw = this.$route.query.pw
    }
})

export default router
```

and this is part of login.vue

```
export default {
        name: "test",
        function() {
            return {
                id: "",
                pw: "",
            };
        },
        methods: {
            test() {
                axios.post("/login", {
                    id: this.userId,
                    pw: this.password
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    if(response.data.code === 200) {

                    }
                })
        },
        mounted : function() {
            this.load();
        }
}
```

i don't know what is wrong in my code.
my explain is too bad. sorry. but i'm trying to do my best

Comment: You are assigning the Login component to the routes property which is incorrect. You must assign the routes array that you have declared at the top, to the routes property of your VueRouter.

Comment: Hi, @junbeom. There is one issue I realised. You should not have params in your login route. Using query strings for password is very unsecure. Please get the value of your password from a form.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `routes` to the Login component.

Replace

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: Login
});
```

with

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"Hello world" example (Maybe it will be helpful). Click on the link to get `utm_source`:

```js
const User = {
  template: `<div><b>User:</b> {{ this.$route.params.id  }} | <b>utm_source:</b> 
    {{this.$router.currentRoute.query['utm_source']}}</div>`
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User }
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/user/foo?utm_source=facebook">Click her to see the utm_source=facebook of /user/foo?utm_source=facebook</router-link>
  </nav>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```